# Create a view from specific Node ID's

Tags: 7, views

I want to create a view with specific nodes. How can I tell views specific node ID's in a list to display?

So for example, I want an unformatted list with node id's 33, 30, and 15.

I tried using the Filter Criteria: Content:NodeID. The problem is that it only allows for numeric value evaluation. It works when i specify using ONE node id. If I add another, it doesn't display anything. If I add another filter using Content:NodeID and specify another node. It also doesn't do anything.

It allows for a regex, but I'm not sure that even with a regex it would allow me to drop in a list of NID's.

Comment: Provide node ids as argument to views. Its simple i think.

Comment: Yea I tried doing that in the filter criteria... but it didn't work because once you add ANOTHER Node ID. Nothing shows up.

Comment: depending on what version of drupal you are running, http://drupal.org/project/viewsphpfilter provides what you are looking for.

Comment: Yea, Sorry I didn't specify. I'm running 7. Just changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Jimajamma Do you know if there is an alternative like Views PHP Filter Or http://drupal.org/project/views_node_filter But for D7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If specific means fixed, you can use fixed value for context filter.

1. Add contextual filter *Content: Nid*.
2. Allow multiple values for this filter in *More* fieldset.
3. Input your NIDs as a default value, where `+` means OR:

[image]

In some cases [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) can be useful.

Comment: Thank You! I tried this... But forgot the multiple values check mark! ::Facepalm::